# Using container for Linux applications?

Tags: linux

I am experimenting with multiple versions of [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page).
This involves downloading different versions and variants of source code, and running the usual: `configure`, `make` and `make install`.

The problem is I can't install multiple versions simultaneously because they use the same install script. I need to uninstall (`make uninstall`) before I install another one. This only works if I have kept the makefile of the installed binaries.

I think what I would like to do is something similar to Python's `virtualenv`. A standalone Linux user(?) environment for each application that I can easily remove.

Is there such a thing? Or is my approach completely flawed?

Comment: You could either use the `chroot` command or use `./configure --prefix=/path/to/installation` to install it elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach for such cases is [`docker container`](https://www.docker.com/). Docker is a container-based virtualization technology, In which you can build your customized Linux-based environment and host your application inside it. thereafter, that means, you have containerized your application and its ready to be distributed and run easily.